# Message dialog not display from service in Windows 8

Tags: windows, delphi

I create a simple application service using Delphi, that service will show massage when it start. at properties of service i set Interactive = true.
the problem is when i test in windows XP it work fine and display dialog massage, but in windows 8 this service not display massage and service is running. i have read issue from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

but still not display massage from my service. and this is my code:

```
unit MainService;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, SvcMgr, Dialogs,
  Registry;

type
  TEW_Main_Service = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
    procedure ServiceAfterUninstall(Sender: TService);
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  EW_Main_Service: TEW_Main_Service;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  EW_Main_Service.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TEW_Main_Service.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TEW_Main_Service.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  Keyms: string;
begin
  Keyms := '\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\' + Self.Name;
  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WRITE);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.OpenKey('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\' + Self.Name, false) then
    begin
      Reg.WriteString('Description', 'This is Service test Prototype for waranty service');
      Reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TEW_Main_Service.ServiceAfterUninstall(Sender: TService);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  Key: string;
begin
  // Delete registry entries for event viewer.
  Key := '\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\' + Self.Name;
  Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WRITE);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if Reg.KeyExists(Key) then
      Reg.DeleteKey(Key);
  finally
    Reg.Free;
end;
end;

procedure TEW_Main_Service.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ShowMessage('blablablablabla');
    Sleep(1000);
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);

  end;
end;
end.
```

did i miss something? Any thought about this?

Comment: They isolated services into the session 0 in Vista. Bastards! :)

Comment: Services can't interact with the desktop. This has been the case since Windows Vista. You can't show a dialog without interacting with the desktop. Therefore, you can't use `ShowMessage` or `MessageDlg` or display any other user interface from a service.

Comment: i have set 'Allow service to interact with Desktop'. but still not work. - @KenWhite

Comment: can be fix or not? @TLama

Comment: Read my answer to the linked question. Windows Vista stopped services from interacting with the desktop. Setting *Allow service to interact with Desktop* has no meaning with Vista and above. After Windows Vista, *services cannot interact with the desktop*. I wrote that in my last comment as well. *Allow service to interact with desktop* stopped working when Vista was released. It has no meaning for Windows versions after XP. So no, it cannot be "fixed", because it's not broken - it was removed when Windows Vista was released.

Comment: I just know it,
Thanks a lot @KenWhite

Comment: *Allow service to interact with Desktop* does still have an effect. Just a different one from XP.